# Completion handler not working as expected in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I have these two functions below, using a completion handler. The questions is highlighted in comments of the 2nd function... why is the `result` part getting executed even before the asynchronous call in function `checforViolationStatus()` been completed.

```
func checkViolationStatus(usr: PFUser, completion: (result: Int32) -> Void) {
    var violations: Int32 = 0
    var query = PFQuery(className: PF_BLOCKEDUSERS_CLASS_NAME)
    query.whereKey(PF_BLOCKEDUSERS_USER, equalTo: usr)


    query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Result = \(count)")

            //The result here returned is 4, I can see it but always ZERO(0) gets printed in the main function. Unable to understand why.
            violations = count
        }
    }

    completion(result: violations)

}


    func goToMainMenu() {

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

        self.mCould.checkViolationStatus(PFUser.currentUser()!) {
            (result: Int32) in

            //QUESTION: result is getting returned as ZERO even before the actual asynchronous call in the checkforViolation function has been completed - why????

            if result < 4 {
                //Go to Main Menu Screen
                print("result<=4 so calling segue")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueLoginVCToMainVC", sender: nil)
            } else {
                print("result >=4, so should not be doing anything")
            }

            print("Number of Violations Received Back: \(result)")

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Downvoted because you make exactly the same mistake as in your previous question, without doing what I so carefully explained in my answer there.

Comment: yep, silly me. Yep you are right. wish you added it as an answer, would mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Try change your function to this,you should call `completion` in the `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`,this method is async.

Or this function return before `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is finished

```
func checkViolationStatus(usr: PFUser, completion: (result: Int32) -> Void) {
var violations: Int32 = 0
var query = PFQuery(className: PF_BLOCKEDUSERS_CLASS_NAME)
query.whereKey(PF_BLOCKEDUSERS_USER, equalTo: usr)


query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        print("Result = \(count)")

        //The result here returned is 4, I can see it but always ZERO(0) gets printed in the main function. Unable to understand why.
        violations = count
        completion(result: violations)

    }
}
}
```